# How do I enable CDN on windows azure

Tags: azure

I a trying to enable CDN on azure, with a free hosting account.I try following these instructions and I go through part 1 http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/ but now I can't seem to find preview portal.I don't know if the instructions been updated or not.

Answer (score 4):

The **Take me to the previous portal** link no longer exists. In order to get back to the old portal, you need to click your email address / name in the top right corner and choose the **Previous portal** option. Once you are back on the old portal you can follow the rest of the  tutorial.